# Hatcher's Theorem 3.26 on orientable of closed connected $n$-manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Part (a) of the theorem is as follows:

Let $M$ be a closed connected $n$-manifold. Then

(a) If $M$ is $R$-orientable, the map $H_n(M;R) \rightarrow H_n(M|x;R) \approx R$ is an isomorphism for all $x \in M$.

I am wondering what the map he is referring to. I tried to look at the proof to deduce what the map is but he uses some abstract lemma that I don't really comprehend (to be honest I have found the entire section on orientations and homology to be vague and nearly unreadable due to lack of details).

I THINK he is referring to the quotient map from the long exact sequence of the pair $(M,M-x)$ but this is only my best guess.

Comment: Your guess is correct. That's how Hatcher defines $H_n(M|x;R)$, namely as $H_n(M,M-x;R)$ which you will see if you find the definition of $H_n(M|x;R)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher yeah I'm aware of his definition of $H_n(M|x;R)$. It's just that it's frustrating when he doesn't define these maps or isomorphisms clearly because I'm not an expert on this stuff, I'm learning it for the first time, so being more specific would be helpful rather than trying to make (educated) guesses. This has been more of an issue in this section on orientations and homology than in any previous section.

Comment: The map $H_n(M;R) =  H_n(M,\emptyset,R) \to H_n(M,M-x;R) = H_n(M|x;R)$ is the induced homomorphism of the inclusion of pairs $(M,\emptyset) \to (M,M-x)$. You'll also find a definition for induced homology homomorphisms in the category of topological pairs somewhere in Hatcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a lot of unwinding definitions... if $A$ is a subset of $X$ then we can look at the group of "relative cocycles" $C_n(X,A;R):=C_n(X;R)/C_n(A;R)$. Then you check that the boundary maps $\partial:C_n(X;R)\to C_{n-1}(X;R)$ send $C_n(A;R)\to C_{n-1}(A;R)$, so $\partial$ induces a well-defined map $\partial:C_n(X,A;R)\to C_{n-1}(X,A;R)$.

Now, when taking the homology $H_n(X;R)=Z_n(X;R)/B_n(X;R)$, you check that under the "natural map" $C_n(X;R)\to C_n(X,A;R)$, elements of $B_n(X;R)$ are sent to $B_n(X,A;R):=\operatorname{im}\partial\subseteq C_n(X,A;R)$ (and similarly for elements of $Z_n$) so there is a well-defined natural map on homology $H_n(X;R)\to H_n(X,A;R)$.

Now, the case in question is just taking $X=M$ and $A=M-\{x\}$. If you're trying to write out this map $H_n(M;R)\to H_n(M|x;R)$ explicitly, you just need to follow the "procedure" outlined above and be careful. It is definitely tedious, but once you write it out and see what's going on it'll begin to feel more natural.